# Express Amplify Serverless/GraphQL vs Express Server-Side backend

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, graphql, aws-amplify

What are the pros and cons of using Amplify Express serverless  https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-rest/express-server/q/platform/js/
or Amplify GraphQL
compared to using Express hosted server-side (REST or GraphQL) for mobile app backend?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on how you would host your "Express hosted server-side"?

The big advantage of Amplify is that it's serverless, meaning it scales automaticaly.
If you were for example to host your Express on EC2, you will have to manage scaling yourself (+ have to manage your Node server, etc)